# Should we accept donations of tainted money?

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, gezel-stealing

A lot has been written on whether donations of tainted money should be accepted.  The money is tainted either because it is ill-gotten or because the donor is ethically challenged (e.g., sexual predator, history of illegal activities, etc.).  Agreement is not universal.  I would like to find a halachic source with clear guidance.  In particular, answers to:

1. If the donated money saves lives (hospitals, medical research, etc.), should it be automatically accepted?
2. If the donated money does not save lives (synagogues, yeshivot, etc.), should it be returned or unilaterally redirected to a purpose that saves lives?
3. If the money must be returned, should it be returned to the donor, to its rightful owners if they can be identified, or to the authorities?
4. Shouldn't the donor be allowed to perform the mitzvah of tzedakah, with or without teshuvah?

Comment: Rb Moshe Feinstein implies that if accepting the money implies that you agree with either the ill gotten manner in which the money was earned or with the anti-Torah behaviour of the donor then it is *assur* to accept this money because of the *issur* of *chanuphah* (flattery).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? You write that "A lot has been written" about this. Obviously "Agreement is not universal", it rarely is in Judaism, so what do you expect in an answer? Presumably, each authority would say that their writings are correct and should be followed.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Source?

Comment: @IsraelReader See שו"ת אגרות משה או"ח ב' סימן נ"א

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Thank you. My understanding of R' Moshe’s words, is that if you don’t explicitly condone his earning money in a non-kosher manner, and you also don't mention his anti-Torah behavior (ex. merely saying that he's a very generous person, and his charity is very helpful to the community), then there is no transgression of "Chanufah" involved here.

Comment: @IsraelReader I agree with your reading, however it would appear to me that by extrapolation: Reb Moshe is discussing a case where the donor earned their money in a *kosher* manner but their religious behaviour was retrograde. Therefore his question revolves around whether it is evident from your honouring this person that you condone his behaviour. So by extension it would appear that if it is evident that the money itself was earned in a non-kosher manner then certainly your acceptance thereof constitutes approval of his actions in earning it and is *assur*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE In the majority of cases, it’s not self-evident that all of person’s money was earned in a non-kosher manner. It’s quite possible, that the person also has legitimate sources of income, especially if he needs to camouflage his illegitimate income. Therefore, since money is fungible, there should be no issue in accepting charity money from them, since it’s possible that the money being given to you is from the “kosher” money.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Also, even if you know that a person has no “kosher” income, I don’t see that R’ Moshe would hold that mere acceptance of charity from him, without mentioning a word about his sources of income, constitutes explicit approval of his actions. It simply was not a matter of discussion, and no act of “Chanufah” transpired.

Comment: @IsraelReader Per Reb Moshe. The question is, what is the *shakla ve'tarya* in the gemara quoted there. How does *naphshach hitzalta* answer *dilma chas ve'shalom hechezakti yedei ovrei aveirah*? *Ela mai* even on the *tzad* that your actions can be interpreted as *chanuphah* there is still an *issur*, which in the gemara's case was only *mutar* because it was *pikuach nephesh*. So if the person is a known gangster, he is not better than the murderer in the gemara's story.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE -- " if accepting the money implies that you agree..."  How can anyone know whether it "implies" that?  You accept the money for a stated honorable purpose.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi That is exactly the problem. It is dishonourable for the Torah for you to allow someone who acts dishonourably to achieve honour via the Torah.

Answer (score 4):

R Shimon Taub in [The laws of tzedakah and maaser](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195893.html) addresses your first question

> If a Jew who deliberately transgresses major mitzvot (e.g., Shabbos)
> wants to give *tzedakah* to poor people, one may accept his donation.
> It is questionable if *tzedakah* may be accepted from such a Jew for a
> *shul* but it has become a custom to do so for a *shul* or *yeshiva*.

Based on that, the answers to your first two questions is that one can accept the money.

Regarding your third question, R Ephraim Zalman Galinski in his book Right on the money, pp. 192ff discusses donations from a thief and brings the [SA CM 369:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.369.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (his translation)

> People who are known to be thieves, and all of their monies are stolen
> monies, etc... one may not benefit from them.

R Galinski explains that, if funds were received from an individual who stole them, as long as the original owners never gave up hope of recovering their money, it is forbidden to use these donations [and they have to return the money]. Of course, it is possible the thief might have other financial resources coming from honest activities which could provide a leniency with regard to institutions who received donations from him.

Since we see above that, in many cases, the money can be accepted, the fourth question becomes less relevant.

Comment: Thanks!  On question 3, you "have to return the money".  My question was: to whom?  The donor?  The wronged individuals?  The authorities?  Also, question 4 is relevant in cases where you "may not" accept the money.

Comment: If the money is stolen, it follows the laws of lost and found. If you find an object and can't identify the owner, you announce the loss, wait for the owner to identify the loss and keep the money until someone comes. If the money has no *simanim*, e.g., if the sum is not in itself significant, or if you believe the owner has given up finding it, you can use it. So as you write, you have to return it to the owners if they can be rightfully identified

Answer (score 1):

In Egypt a case was discussed about donations from unsavory sources. In the end Moreinu Shim'on ruled that they could accept donations even for sifrei torot as long as you remove potential stumbling blocks from the donations, such as not allowing names to be inscribed on objects that may remind others of their sins.

"R. Raphael Aaron ben Shimon, Nehar Mitzrayim (Alexandria, 1908), vol. 1, p. 12a, discusses a case where not only did the prostitute donate a parochet, but she also inscribed her name into it in golden letters. As R. Raphael notes, this is especially problematic since if allowed then people praying in synagogue would see her name staring down upon them and this would invariably lead to improper thoughts. (He adds that this particular prostitute had been with a lot of the young Jewish men.) Therefore, he ruled that the parochet could not be used and any gifts from prostitutes to the synagogue could not have their names on it. He also mentions a prostitute who donated a sefer Torah to the synagogue (!), and this was accepted on the condition that her name not appear on it.."

Source: https://seforimblog.com/2014/08/the-pew-report-and-orthodox-community/